# Access entire C drive from X source boot?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, command-line, boot, cmd.exe

I would like to be able to access the entire C drive as my title says from booting in x source cmd whilst in repair mode, is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried exactly?  It should be as simple as chaning the working directory to the drive letter assigned to the system partition, it might not be C, you should give us more information to work with.

Comment: Have you tried typing `C:` in the cmd on recovery?

Answer (score 22):

Booting to WinRE will give you the tools to access your entire `C:\` but you need to determine what drive letter WinRE has given to your `C:\` for the session you have booted to. To achieve this you use `DISKPART`.

1. Boot to your WinRE ("repair mode" as you call it)
2. Type `DISKPART` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Type `LIST VOL` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. You will need to identify which is your system drive letter - this is often easily identifiable as they are often titled `SYSTEM` or `WINDOWS` or `WIN8` etc. and often have the volume capacity (another easy bit of information to identify your `C:\`).
5. Make a note of the drive letter assigned by the WinRE environment - it may not be `C:`
6. Type `EXIT` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> - The command prompt will return to the `X:\Sources>` prompt
7. Type your noted `C:` (exclude any trailing `\`) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> - it should change the working directory to the drive letter. To verify it is your `C:` type `dir` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you should see your `Users` folder which you can enter into (`cd Users`) and `dir` again to see your user account.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so I have made it into diskpart, listed 3 volumes c, e and f. I exit going back to x source  run cd: \e but the next line returns x source again.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect.  Chris indicates the correct syntax to use.

Comment: You need to type: `e:` then press `Enter`

Comment: Yeah sorry that was a typo. I have ended up using pushd command to get to the drive unfortunately ordinary cd didn't want to work

Comment: That's because you don't use `cd` to change drive letters :)

Comment: You only need to type E: (no cd, or anything, just E:)

Comment: Mark this as an answer if it solved your problem, @ManWithNoName.

Comment: Good answer, could you stress that one needs to type just `C:` without the backslash `\\` @Kinnectus? I suppose many readers might overlook this (me included).

Comment: Updated step 7, which I believe is where the confusion is.