# Why do Windows “This PC” folders look different on two different machines and how can I change that?

Tags: windows-10

I have two machines running Windows 10 (version 1909): On one machine, my “This PC” folders look like only icons in details view:

[image: Just_Icons]

On another machine, they look like folders with icons:

[image: Folders_with_Icons]

Why does this happen and how do I get both machines to appear as just icons?

**Update 21-NOV-2020:**

I am able to get all EXCEPT the "Downloads" and "My Music" folders to look like just icons by editing the HKCU registry per [this tenforums.com article](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/81222-change-icons-folders-pc-windows-10-a.html). I don't know why it's not working for "Downloads" and "My Music"

[image: Fixed Desktop, My Pictures, and My Videos]

Comment: Are both machines using Windows 10?

Comment: Probably the two computers are using different themes  and possibly performance settings (Advanced System Properties)

Comment: You might also confirm if both are different versions too (e.g. 20H2 on one and 1909 on the other).

Comment: All great comments! Both are Windows 10 and both use version 1909. @John are there specific settings in Advanced System Properties I should review?

Comment: Look through the visual settings. I use all but shadows and see your second rendition above.

Comment: @John I don't want the second rendition. I want the first. I've tried all settings in Advanced System Profiles and none change the "folder-with-icon" to "just-icon"

Comment: Does anyone know how to turn it from "folders-with-icons" to just "icons"?

Comment: So far, in looking at my machines here (all properly set up, all simple themes), I see "folders with icons" on folders that display this way.  You can try using the Details view and that simplifies the icons.  That is a Windows Explorer function. I use Details for working folders and so the issue does not occur in my regular work.

Comment: @John The error only occurs when the folders are shown in Details view. That is the original problem. I want the folders to appear as just icons when ThisPC is shown in Details view.

Comment: I am not sure what operating system error would cause this. I will look around but at this point I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single Windows icon usually contains multiple images, of various sizes and color depths. The icons you are using contain 8 sizes, ranging from 256×256 to 16×16 pixels.

Microsoft has made the artistic decision that the designs of its icons should be simplified at smaller sizes, because there is no room for fine details. For these icons, the folder is shown in the 40×40 and larger, and omitted from the 32×32 and smaller sizes.

To have folder-less images at 40×40 and up, you have to find icons that are folder-less at all sizes, or make your own by using an icon editor and rummaging through the Windows resources for bits and pieces that you can edit together.

Comment: In laymen's terms, the resolution on one of my machines is higher than the other and Windows shows different icons at different resolutions. I can confirm changing the resolution on my other machine changes the icons. What registry key setting controls this feature and where are the folderless icons it is pointing to? I cannot find these in imageres.dll or shell32.dll.

Comment: Interestingly, I can change the default icon to point to folderless icons in HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID for all but My Music and Downloads folders. Adding a "DefaultIcon" key does not work for these folders.

Comment: I have tried 32x32, 64x64, and 128x128 icons (created in Gimp) and updated the registry to point to them, but Downloads and My Music don't work. It works for Desktop, My Pictures, My Videos, and My Documents, but not these two folders. Why?

Comment: I think I see now what is going on. The icons for the folders that work are all the same at each size (256, 64, 32, etc.). I cannot find icons in imageres.dll that are the same at all sizes for My Music and Downloads, which is why they aren't working

Answer (score 1):

Adding this as "Part 2" to @David_Lasher's answer. `C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll` has folderless icon files for all resolutions for all ThisPC folder icons except My Music and Downloads (why I do not know).

To create a new Downloads icon (same steps for My Music), find an image you like online then download Gimp. First size and create a 256x256 image in one layer in Gimp, the successively duplicate and resize multiple layers until you create the 64, 48, 40, 32, 24, 20, and 16x16 images. Finally, export this as an icon (not save as). A tutorial can be found here: [Craete Multi-Size Icon in Gimp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkuZqJCFaog).

Next, download [IconsExtract](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html) and [ResourceHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/). I just use IconsExtract to find the IconIndex number of the icon I want to edit. Most Windows icons are in C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll. Open this dll in IconsExtract and look for icon 184 (Downloads; My Music is 108). If you right-click and select File Properties, you will see as @David_Lasher describes above that all icons below 40x40 are folderless while all those above have folders.

In Windows 10 since Build 1903, the icons in imageres.dll are no longer in `C:\Windows\System32`. Instead, the are now in a file `C:\Windows\SystemResources\imageres.dll.mun` (see [Icons no longer in imageres.dll in Windows 10 1903 - 4kb file](https://superuser.com/questions/1480268/icons-no-longer-in-imageres-dll-in-windows-10-1903-4kb-file)). Make a copy of this file, paste it on your Desktop, and rename it to `imageres.dll`. Open this file in `ResourceHacker`. Open "Icon Group" in the folders pane in the left, scroll to 184, open it, right-click the 1033 under it and select "Replace Icon" and choose your icon. (Similar instructions are here: [Windows 7: Icons - Change Using Resource Hacker](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/73191-icons-change-using-resource-hacker.html)).

Lastly, save the modified dll on your desktop and rename it back to `imageres.dll.mun`. Then, take ownership of your `C:\Windows\SystemResources` folder, rename the `imageres.dll.mun` file to something like `imageres_OLD.dll.mun` and copy paste your new `imageres.dll.mun`.

Restart your computer, and good-bye crappy folders!!

BTW: Before you restart, be sure to do 2 things:

1. Create a system restore point
2. Create a repair disc (on a flash drive nowadays)

If you BSOD your computer:

1. Launch the repair disc
2. Go to the command line (you will be in `X:\` drive)
3. Type `DISKPART`
4. Type `LIST VOL`
5. Identify which is your system drive letter (it won't necessarily be `C` anymore)
6. Type `EXIT` to get out of DISKPART
7. Type the drive letter and colon (nothing else). For exmaple, if the system drive is `D:\`, type `D:` then enter to switch drives.
8. `cd` to `D:\Windows\SystemResources`
9. Delete the current `.mun` file by typing `del /f imageres.dll.mun`
10. Rename the saved `.mun` file by typing `rename imageres_OLD.dll.mun imageres.dll.mun` (this is case sensitive)

You now should be able to boot into Windows normally. (see [Access entire C drive from X source boot? [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/1117591/access-entire-c-drive-from-x-source-boot/1117593))

Happy hacking!